# post api call using websocket in Angular not working

Tags: angular, websocket

I am building a sample application in which i am doing a post api call . The main objective is to send a query using POST api call which in return give data from api as response. The main feature of this api is that it gives updated data after every 1 minute (continuously).

**Problem**: The main problem is that api is showing the updated data for a particular time instance (example: 16:30 PM) but to see the updated data after a minute or two(example: 16:32 PM) , i have to refresh the page every time . I am trying to solve this problem using Web Socket to keep calling api after particular time interval and to update the data on the front end but somehow it is not working.

**Please find the below code for your reference.**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client/build/index';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketService {
socket: any;
readonly uri: string = 'https://apiurlexample.com/api/xxx/xxxxxx';
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
debugger;
// this.socket = io(this.uri);
// this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8890', { query: "foo=bar" });
}
getMessages() {
debugger;
let observable = new Observable(observer => {
this.socket = io(this.uri);
this.socket.on('', (data: any) => {
observer.next(data);
});
return () => {
this.socket.disconnect();
};
})
return observable;
}
listen(eventName: string) {
debugger;
return new Observable((subscriber) => {
this.socket.on(eventName, (data: any) => {
subscriber.next(data);
})
});
}
emit(eventName: string, data: any) {
this.socket.emit(eventName, data);
}
getAllData(data: any) {
return this.http.post(`https://apiurlexample.com/api/xxx/xxxxxx`, data);
}
}
```

**any solution please ?**

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is correct. However, you only set up websocket in frontend, have you broadcast it continuously from backend?
I mean you have your socket ready to listen for changes from backend, but does the backend send anything after a minute or two?

Edit:

Or you can imply just add an interval:

```
setInterval(() => {
    getData(); 
}, 60000)
```

Comment: Quyen Huynh: yes backend is sending the updated data after every minute. But to reflect that in front end i have to manually refresh page after a minute.

Comment: Can you please try to console.log something to ensure that it's working in backend? Or you can just use `setInterval`